# Use same Postgres WITH in multiple queries

Tags: postgresql

I would like to use same `WITH` in multiple queries.

```
WITH x AS (INSERT ... RETURNING id)
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (x);
INSERT INTO t3 VALUES (x);
```

How would I do that? Do I have to create a temporary table instead?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can chain multiple CTEs that perform an INSERT:

```
with x (id) as (
  insert into ... 
  returning id
), t2_insert as (
  insert into t2 (id)
  select id
  from x
)
insert into t3
select id
from x;
```